# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "echo", expecting ")"

Tags: php

I just tried to add this line

```
data-tippy-content="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author', true); ?>"
```

into some php code. The result is this:

```
<?php
the_title( '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark" class="modal-link"  data-tippy-content="'echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author', true)'">', '</a>' );
?>
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?

The error message I got is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "echo", expecting ")"
```

Comment: Remove the `echo` before `get_post_meta()`.

Comment: Strange. I removed the `echo` and now I'm getting this warning: `unexpected identifier "get_post_meta", expecting ")" `

Comment: You need to concat it `data-tippy-content="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author', true) . '">',`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php the_title( '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) .'" rel="bookmark" class="modal-link"  data-tippy-content="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "Author", true). '">,</a>' );  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, had to add two quoutation marks to make it work `>','</a>`